# For what reason htmlspecialchar() default charset changed from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8

Tags: php

According to http://php.net/htmlspecialchars the default value for the charset argument changed from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 in PHP 5.4.

If you follow the discussion of this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61354 here, you quickly realize that this lead to major difficulties in maintaining legacy PHP-Code. We've run into similar problems.

Explanations like "most people use UTF-8" in this post http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/28/htmlspecialchars-improvements-in-PHP-5-4.html are really weird.

As far as I know, htmlspecialchars() quotes everything all right in UTF8, even if ISO-8859-1 is set. People using non-ASCII-charsets had to set the parameter... ok, but they are not affected by a change to the default behavior, either. I've written a lot of UTF-8 code and never had a problem with htmlspecialchars() using ISO-8859-1 before.

So why change this behavior? Or am I overlooking some security issues? I just want to understand it (no code solution needed!).

Comment: No idea what the real reason is, but I'm guessing it's for future compatibility, when unicode rules the world and things like iso8859 are just a distant nightmare.

Comment: Future considerations would be a valid argument, imho. I would get rid of old ISO-8859-1 code a fast as possible, if I could decide it.

Comment: The change in PHP 5.4 was simply to switch from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 when you do not specify a charset. This seems like a config issue rather than code change.

Comment: Default Linux kernel uses UTF-8 in every system i've used.. I welcome this change!

Comment: This reminds me of [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br)'s backwards incompatible change added during the fad of XHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour is changed from ISO-8859-1 as a default to UTF-8 as a default because UTF-8 is more commonly used.

ISO-8859-1 covers Latin characters while UTF-8 supports a much larger set of characters. This is why UTF-8 is often used in favor of ISO-8859-1.

---

As for why they chose to break compatibility: I guess they thought it was a good idea. Maybe the underestimated the impact this would have. I can see this being a bit of a snag for entry-level developers.

This is a potential fix for this breaking change:

```
function myhtmlspecialchars($string, $flags = null, $encoding = "ISO-8859-1", $double_encode = true) {
    if ($flags === null) { $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401; }
    return htmlspecialchars($string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
}
```

And then simply replace `htmlspecialchars` by `myhtmlspecialchars` in your code.

---

As of version 5.6.0 the default is `default_charset`. So this only impacts applications running on a version between `5.4.x` and `5.5.x`

Comment: Or you can just change the default charset in your php.ini if that is an option.

Comment: Not for PHP `5.4.x` and `5.5.x`

Comment: Have you a reference, that this behavior changed in PHP 5.6? I could not find anything here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.php

Comment: Check the doc for http://php.net/htmlspecialchars : _From PHP 5.6.0, default_charset value is used as default. From PHP 5.4.0, UTF-8 is the default. PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default._

Comment: Thanks for the hint with PHP 5.6.0, that makes me believe, that there is still some common sense for the language. I give it the answered flag. Though, your solution with myhtmlspecialchars is not the always possible. I guess you do not have commercial third party libraries in mind, where you cannot change functions without loosing the ability to update the lib easily. You have to pay their developers for the change or you are likely doing something ugly using runkit with runkit_function_rename then.